# How do I printf a map in OCaml?

Tags: dictionary, printf, ocaml

```
open Map
open Pretty

let d_doc () (x : doc) : doc = x

let d_str () = text

let d_map d_k d_v () m : doc =
  printf "{%a}"
         d_doc
         (Map.fold (fun k v acc -> printf "%a, %a -> %a" d_doc acc d_k k d_v v) m (text ""))
```

tells me "Error: Unbound value Map.fold".  How do I do this?  (I'd like either a pointer to a reference that explains how to use Map functions (or module functions in general), a standard library pretty printer for maps, and/or a fix for my code.)

Comment: Your question title is misleading. You're really wondering why `Map.fold` is not found, which isn't about printing at all. Are you following an example from a specific book? We also need to know which libraries you've loaded.

Comment: No, my ultimate goal is to printf a Map, from the standard library.  I have some template code from a pset on program analysis, and I'm trying to printf my map for debugging.  Map.fold was just the first thing I tried, and if someone just tells me why Map.fold isn't found, but it doesn't lead me to know how to print out a Map, then I won't be satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Here's the non-satisfying answer: `Map` is a functor, not a module. So it doesn't have a `fold` function per se. It produces modules that have a `fold` function. If you just want to debug, it might be faster to focus on the actual modules you have (applications of `Map.Make`).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post is old, but for the future visitor, the following works:

```ml
module IntMap = Map.Make(Int)
type map = string IntMap.t

let pp_map ppf (m : map) =
  IntMap.iter (fun k v -> Format.fprintf ppf "%d -> %s@\n" k v) m

let _ =
  IntMap.empty
  |> IntMap.add 4 "hello"
  |> IntMap.add 2 "world"
  |> Format.printf "%a" pp_map
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print out a map using sexplib quite conveniently.  Here's how you'd do it using Core.

```
open Core.Std

let map = Int.Map.of_alist_exn [1,"one"; 2,"two"; 3,"three"]
let () =
  (<:sexp_of<string Int.Map.t>> map)
  |> Sexp.to_string_hum
  |> print_endline
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could elaborate on this a bit. I get an error message "Unbound module Core". Also you presumably write `<string Int.Map.t>` because your map is from Int to String, what if its a different domain and range?